# Burninate [what-is] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I mean come on guys, do we really need [such a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3547590)?

It [has not even been used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/what-is) and I see no point in having it.

Does anyone agree?

---

hold on, why am I thinking it does exist?

First of all, someone is suggesting an edit on it! If it didn't exist then a suggested edit couldn't be proposed on it?

Secondly,

[image]

How does it not exist while it does? I can't understand that...

It may be removed after 24 hrs if not used etc but it does in fact exist right now.

Comment: Can someone contact Matt and tell him/her that such questions are off-topic on SO?

Comment: He should be banned from suggesting edits pretty soon. Of his last 15 suggested edits, only one is approved.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby great! glad you've said that

Comment: The tag has 0 posts associated with it and will be removed again within 24 hours. This happens, people make mistakes and tags like these get cleaned up pretty quickly these days. No need to make a new Meta post about each and every one you see.

Comment: @Mystical Their wiki tag edits were terrible. Too bad that so many crept in already.

Comment: @Mystical or in 18 rep he won't need approval at all and he can wreck whatever havoc he desires

Comment: The tag was created by [Matt on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1642028/revisions "See revision #13 and 14"). But it was rolled back. Then Matt suggested an edit for this tag which was rejected. So the was created. But it will be removed (as you know) soon..

Comment: I really didn't get you. What do you want to ask here? Should we ban users from creating a tag? Or should we ban the user from suggesting edits on tags which they have created? Or anything else?

Comment: I think he's asking why the tag continued to exist after it was removed from all questions.  If so, this is a dupe of every other time that question gets asked, usually a few times a week...

Answer (score 0):

You can type [any tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gibbalebalabel-oomph) into the bar and it will show up as zero questions asked if it doesn't exist, so be careful not to take it as indication of such.

In the off chance this tag was actually created, it has either been destroyed or will be automatically removed in at most 24 hours as it has no questions.

Comment: haven't noticed that [your link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gibbalebalabel-oomph) is actually different from [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/what-is)? This tag HAS been created but probably removed from a question and the point I am having is people start creating tag wikis and excerpts for it.. why award someone +2 for an edit to a tag we didn't need in first place?

Comment: @mehow: Rejected edits don't award reputation.

Comment: @mehow My link is to demonstrate that the tag does not exist currently. It may have been created at some point, but it has been ended.

Comment: I know @TimeTravelingBobby. Because this one happened not to be review by robo-reviewers but how about [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1477611/zogthedog)

Comment: @mehow For the most part, she seems to be adding relevant tag wikis. I don't see the problem.

Comment: Is there something incorrect in my answer?